# Facing error "You must be logged in to the server", while deploying kubernetes manifest to aws eks using github actions and AWS OIDC

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, token, amazon-iam, openid-connect

Complete error:

> error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)

Code snippet:

```
name: Deploy images from ECR to k8s
on:
  workflow_dispatch
env:
  AWS_REGION: "us-east-1"
  ENV: "prod"
permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read
jobs:
  deployment:
    name: Deploy application to EKS cluster
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code from GitHub to runner
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
      with:
        role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/oidc_identity
        role-duration-seconds: 1200
        aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

    - name: Install kubectl
      uses: azure/setup-kubectl@v3
        # with:
        #   version: '1.27' # default is latest stable
      id: install-kubectl      
    - name: Update kube config
      run: |
        aws eks update-kubeconfig --name k8s-voting-app --region ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
        cat /home/runner/.kube/config

    - name: Deploy application images to EKS cluster
      run: |
        kubectl version --short
        kubectl apply -f k8s-specifications/db-secret.yaml
```

EKS Cluster error

[image]

While searching for the solution, i read somewhere that "aws cli" in the github action runner (ubuntu 22.04), needs to assume the oidc role to run the kubernetes manifests on the kubernetes cluster.

Command for which is:

```
aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity \
    --duration-seconds 1200 \
    --role-session-name "app1" \
    --provider-id "www.amazon.com" \
    --policy-arns "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/q=webidentitydemopolicy1","arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/webidentitydemopolicy2" \
    --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/FederatedWebIdentityRole \
    --web-identity-token "Atza%7CIQEBLjAsAhRFiXuWpUXuRvQ9PZL3GMFcYevydwIUFAHZwXZXXXXXXXXJnrulxKDHwy87oGKPznh0D6bEQZTSCzyoCtL_8S07pLpr0zMbn6w1lfVZKNTBdDansFBmtGnIsIapjI6xKR02Yc_2bQ8LZbUXSGm6Ry6_BG7PrtLZtj_dfCTj92xNGed-CrKqjG7nPBjNIL016GGvuS5gSvPRUxWES3VYfm1wl7WTI7jn-Pcb6M-buCgHhFOzTQxod27L9CqnOLio7N3gZAGpsp6n1-AJBOCJckcyXe2c6uD0srOJeZlKUm2eTDVMf8IehDVI0r1QOnTV6KzzAI3OY87Vd_cVMQ"
```

i need the web-identity-token, but despite looking everywhere i am unable to determine how do i generate a web-identity-token to be used within github actions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the `aws-auth` ConfigMap.

`kubectl edit configmap aws-auth -n kube-system`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/AmazonEKSNodeRole
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
    - groups:
      - github-actions
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/your-desired-role
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
```

`github-actions` Group as the example (you should add your desired permissions):

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: read-pods-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
```

Bind the role to the `github-actions` group:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-pods-binding
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: github-actions
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: read-pods-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```